# Date picker(.js) not working in HTML editor but working in fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the working format in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6u43xarm/#run)
 and below is the code i have used in my demo-site i have created a new folder name js and placed datepicker.js inside it. so i linked the following in my html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js"></script>
```

and my datapicker.js code is

```
$(function () {
    $('#departure-date').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showAnim: "fold",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: (function (date) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#return-date').datepicker('show');
            }, 300)
            $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString());
        })
    });

    $('#return-date').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showAnim: "fold",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: (function (date) {
            $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString());
        })
    });
});
```

and my html code is

```
<input  id="departure-date" type="text" placeholder="Depart Date" >
<input type="text" id="return-date" placeholder="return Date">
```

but when i press the above button .js is not being called. please help

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Is jQuery defined?

Comment: @guest271314 I'm sorry i cant understand what you are asking for

Comment: You need to include a version of jQuery. Download the latest release and put it in your js folder and link it like you did for datepicker.js or directly include it like this  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @GladwinJames - you included the jquery file in the page??????

Comment: Its working on jsfiddle.

Comment: @JeetDaloneboy Yes, thats what I have said in the query too it works well in fiddle but its not working in normal editor

Comment: paste you editor code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a version of jQuery. Download the latest release and put it in your js folder and link it like you did for datepicker.js or directly include it like this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If this does not work try

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I am not sure if your single datepicker.js has and error, but if it does try the jquery-ui js which includes it.

I tested it with including the above 2 js sources and it worked fine.

If the direct link to the jquery site js does not work then it is another problem on your page that is not shown to us.

Comment: He is using jquery.

Comment: I downloaded development jquery from http://jquery.com/download/ and linked up to html with <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> but still its not working..

Comment: @Gladwin I updated with 2 new links that should work. Remove your js and jquery links from the page and try the above 2. I tested them with your code and it works.

Comment: @Icewine  Thanks for the backup brother, i hooked theses scripting codes `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>`
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>` and it worked but I still dont no what these are can you please explain??

Comment: These are the google repository for jquery if you want direct links. You can also get the direct links from the jquery.com, they are the same thing. I would recommend a local copy of those files for your JS folder if you expect the user to be able to work offline. The jquery.js is the main jquery needed. If you want to use various jquery ui elements you also need jquery-ui.js(which includes datepicker and other ui related code) If you want a premade style you need a jquery-ui.css style sheet. You can get a template from the jquery-ui website or do everything from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is running absolutly fine on my local machine.
Where i simply used the jQuery and jQueryUI CDN path from

> Google Developer Site
>   [Link](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/)

**Your piece of code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS Datepicker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input  id="departure-date" type="text" placeholder="Depart Date" >
<input type="text" id="return-date" placeholder="return Date">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $('#departure-date').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showAnim: "fold",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: (function (date) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#return-date').datepicker('show');
            }, 300)
            $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString());
        })
    });

    $('#return-date').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showAnim: "fold",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: (function (date) {
            $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString());
        })
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Departure Date]
[image: Return Date]

Answer (score 1):

if you miss place the position of jquery it wont work. hope the below code helps you.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#departure-date').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showAnim: "fold",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: (function (date) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#return-date').datepicker('show');
            }, 300)
            $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString());
        })
    });

    $('#return-date').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showAnim: "fold",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: (function (date) {
            $(this).val($(this).datepicker('getDate').toLocaleDateString());
        })
    });
});
```

```html
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<input  id="departure-date" type="text" placeholder="Depart Date" >
<input type="text" id="return-date" placeholder="return Date">
```